# Can't login in Stratio admin page

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon, stratio

I have installed mesos, ZK, marathon on master computer and now I was trying to install **Stratio Manager**, but first of all problem was **FQDN**, then I added domain name in **/etc/hosts**.

After everything worked and I have got manager view in the web browser, but I am not able to login.

My username is:

```
admin
```

Password is:

```
p@ssw0rd1
```

I can't get what is the problem :(

Comment: What do you mean with you can't log in? BTW, please never ever share passwords online …

Comment: Never mind. Looking at their docs seems to suggest that  `p@ssw0rd1` is their default. Sigh …

Comment: Hi! What version of Stratio Manager are you using? You should be able to connect using with user:admin;password:p@ssw0rd1. If you cannot login using those credentials, you can check the logfile located in `/var/log/sds/manager`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.
I have already solved the problem.
The thing was that program was unable to connect to server. I gave new domainname and hostname and I changed hosts file in cd /ect/hosts . So I got right FQDN and after that everything worked.